error nrpe invalid argument when tryin to start service
when i'm tryin to start nrpe service with : /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe -d -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg
it give me this error :
-bash: /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe: invalid argument
i'm using Sunos solaris 11 as operating system
i'm trying to start nrpe service
